# Inequality in convex set involving gradient vector

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I would appreciate if someone could assist with this question, as I'm not sure how to go about starting it. Something to get me on the right track would help a lot!

We must show that, given that $|\nabla f(y)| \leq L$ for all $y$ in a convex set (of points) $\omega$ (with $L$ fixed), that:

$|f(y_{1}) - f(y_{2})| \leq L|y_{1} - y_{2}|$ for all $y_{1},y_{2} \in \omega$

Thanks!
Lauren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $y_1, y_2 \in \omega$ and consider the function $g(t) = f(ty_1 + (1-t)y_2)$, $t \in [0,1]$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, the mean value theorem gives a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(1) - g(0) = g'(c)$, i.e., $f(y_1) - f(y_2) = g'(c)$. Now $$g'(t) = (y_1 - y_2)\cdot \nabla f(ty_1 + (1-t)y_2)$$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Since $|\nabla f(y)| \le L$ for all $y\in \omega$, $$|g'(t)| \le |y_1 - y_2||\nabla f(ty_1 + (1 - t)y_2)| \le L|y_1 - y_2|$$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Thus $$|f(y_1) - f(y_2)| = |g'(c)| \le L|y_1 - y_2|.$$